# Debug (ASM) running Android Application

Tags: android, debugging, assembly, android-ndk

So I have googled this but just can't find a definitive answer.

I have an Android application which does a type of background calculation. I no longer have access to the source code, and furthermore its written using the NDK so can't use dex2jar.

What I'd like to do is to somehow attach a debugger and see the asm of the calculation to work it out, as I can't think of any other way to do this?

There doesn't seem to be to much information on the web around this.

Answer (score 0):

If the APK is built in debug mode (containing gdbserver), you might get it to work, but you might need to either dissect the ndk-gdb script quite a bit, or build a mock project which ndk-gdb can look at to do its magic.

Alternatively, if you're ok with not stepping through it at runtime (inspecting the registers etc) you can just disassemble the .so files as well. Try `<NDK>/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-*/prebuilt/*/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-objdump -d libfoo.so`. If the detection of arm vs thumb mode doesn't work, you might want to add `-M force-thumb`. This obviously requires more work, and you can't check the intermediate values, but should be doable with almost any library.

Comment: If I open the apk through a zip program I can see a .so file already in there. Would this be the one?..Also its pretty big, like 30MB, so going to be a lot of trawling through it!

Comment: Yes, the .so file is the one you should look at. A 30 MB .so will obviously take ages to disassemble, but if you're lucky you might be able to isolate the parts you want to understand - but being able to inspect it at runtime would of course help a lot. But unfortunately I think that's only doable if the APK is built in debug mode with a gdbserver available. If you'd run it on a rooted device (or e.g. a firmware you've built yourself from AOSP) you might also be able to debug it.

Comment: I do actually have access to rooted (and non rooted) device. How would I go about trying to debug with the rooted device?

Comment: I'm not actually sure in detail - I've only done it for firmwares I've built myself. I found http://redmine.replicant.us/projects/replicant/wiki/GDBDebugging which shows you how to do that. Basically, try installing a gdbserver binary on the device somehow, run it as root to attach to the right process, forward the port via adb, then run arm-linux-androideabi-gdb locally (you can find it in the NDK), skip the sysroot/solib-search-path steps but set the file option (pointing to the .so file) and run the "target" command to attach to the remote gdbserver.